# Can a templating engine like Tiles, Velocity, Freemarker etc be used outside of a web application?

Tags: html, xml, jsp, velocity, tiles

I have a requirement to generate an HTML file from data that will be generated dynamically from a single recordset of a number of database tables. The HTML file will be used as an attachemment in an Email. I can generate the HTML file by manually writing the HTML code but would like to use some sort of templating engine so that i dont have to code the structure of the HTML file and any common aspects of the HTML document (e.g. header banners, footers etc) . I have used Tiles before for a web based struts application. The application i used was based on JSP but the file i would like to generate is pure HTML.

Does anyone know if it is possible to use Tiles or any other templating engine to generate the HTML file? The HTML file will be stored on to the file system instead of it being rendered on to the browser from within an application server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Velocity and Freemarker are usable outside of a web application. They're generic HTML template engines. It's written in their respective [welcome](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/index.html) [pages](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/).

Tiles isn't really in the same league: unless it has changed drastically since I last used, it, it's only able to assemble various page sections together, but each section must be written as a JSP.

Comment: at least Velocity is not even tied to HTML in any way. I have used it to generate Java source, .NET source, CSV, HTML, PDF (via XSL-FO), XML, ... and a number of others.

Comment: Tiles has actually changed quite a bit. I'm fairly sure you can use it w/Velocity or Freemarker, no jsp needed.

Comment: Oh, and Freemarker also has no HTML ties.  All three work with any and all text.